# How to remove special charactor and remove space between charactors?

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scrapy

I am working in scrapy + python. I have tried to extract jobid data from job url can any one guide me this to extract.

http://xxxxx/apply/EkhIMG/Director-Financial-Planning-Analysis.html

I have to extract this content alone "Director-Financial-Planning-Analysis"

also need to remove the special characters too DirectorFinancialPlanningAnalysis

my expected output should be : DirectorFinancialPlanningAnalysis

My spider code is:

```
hxs = Selector(response) 
item = response.request.meta['item']
item ['JobDetailUrl'] = response.url
item ['InternalJobId'] = item ['JobDetailUrl'].re('.*\/(.*?)\.html').groups()
```

My output error:

```
item ['InternalJobId'] = item['JobDetailUrl'].re('.*\/(.*?)\.html')
.groups()
exceptions.AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 're'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`re()` is a method on a `Selector` object, here `response.url` is a string:

```
re.search(r'([a-zA-Z\-]+)\.html$', response.url).group(1).replace('-', '')
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'http://xxxxx/apply/EkhIMG/Director-Financial-Planning-Analysis.html'
>>> re.search(r'([a-zA-Z\-]+)\.html$', s).group(1).replace('-', '')
'DirectorFinancialPlanningAnalysis'
```